# Alternative for \intro in document class knitting patterns class

Tags: graphics

Using `\intro` command text appears on left side and image on right.

- Which command can i use to put the image to the left and text on the right side?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Where did you get that macro `\intro`?

Answer (score 1):

There is no command in the `knittingpattern` class to put the image on the left, but you can define a new command to do that.

The `\intro` command three arguments: the ratio of the columns (this is an optional argument with default value 0.25), the text (which is set in a tabular column of type `m`, which is a paragraph) and the image, which is set using a `includegraphics` command. The size of the first column is calculated as the textwidth minus the fraction of the textwidth as given in the optional first argument (and a small correction for the column separation).

From the source code of the class:

```
\newcommand{\intro}[3][.25]{\begin{tabular}{m{\textwidth - 4\tabcolsep
- #1\textwidth}m{#1\textwidth}}
#2&\fbox{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#3}}
\end{tabular}}
```

For a new command you can switch the columns and the arguments around:

```
\newcommand{\introleft}[3][.25]{\begin{tabular}{m{#1\textwidth}m{\textwidth - 4\tabcolsep
- #1\textwidth}}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#2}}&#3
\end{tabular}}
```

Note that the tabular column specifications have switched (the `m{#1\textwidth}` column is now first), the actual columns have also switched (the `\includegraphics` cell is now second) and the order of the arguments has switched (`#2` is now the image and `#3` is the text).

MWE for this modification, adapted from the package documentation:

```
\documentclass{knittingpattern}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\introleft}[3][.25]{\begin{tabular}{m{#1\textwidth}m{\textwidth - 4\tabcolsep
- #1\textwidth}}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#2}}&#3
\end{tabular}}

\introleft{lion.png}{
Introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction.
Introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction.
Introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction
introduction introduction introduction introduction introduction.
}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Very nice. Where did you get `lion.png` from?

Comment: @PeterWilson It's part of the `knittingpattern` class, http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/knittingpattern/lion.png. But there is also a special page on CTAN about the lion, https://ctan.org/lion.